# Plot means of multiple variables on same x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I apologize if the question doesn't make much sense but essentially I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame("Var1" = c(1,.25,1,.5,.5,.75), 
                 "Var2" = c(.25,.25,.25,.5,1,.75), 
                 "Var3" = c(1,1,1,.5,.5,.25), 
                 "Var4" = c(1,1,1,.75,.75,.75))
```

where all four variables use the same scale. I'd like to plot their means on a simple bar chart, where each variable appears like a group on the x-axis and has its own bar. The y-axis would go from 0-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to reshape your data first and then plot. I use `stack` for this which will return a data frame with columns `values` and `ind`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(stack(df), aes(x = ind, y = values)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun.y = mean) +
  ylim(c(0, 1))
```

[image]